# Issue with multiple callbacks getJSON jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, mapping, getjson

I need to create some marker pop ups that show information from different ajax requests on a map. To make the second call I use an userID that I get from the first call. The information from the second call it shown good, but all the pop ups shown the same name, of the last item from the first call, why this happend, can anyone help me please? many thanks in advance!!!.

```
$.getJSON('url', function (data) { // first call
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {            
        var name= data[i].name;
        var location= data[i].location;
        var userID = data[i].userID;
        var myIcon= data[i].icon;   
        var marker = new L.Marker(location, {title: name, icon: myIcon});// create the marker           
        $.getJSON('https://api.site.com/data/'+userID+'',(function(marker){ // second call using userID
          return function(data2) {
          var info1 = data2.response.tips.items[0].text;
          var info2 = data2.response.tips.items[1].text;
          marker.bindPopup("<div class='popup'>" + name +"</br>"+ info1 +"</br>"+ info2 + "</div>", {maxWidth: '600'}) // create the popup and add it to the marker                     
                }
         })(marker)
        );
      shops.addLayer(marker); // add marker to map layer
      }
```

Comment: You either have to get `name` from the `marker` or add `name` to the variables in your closure.

Comment: sorry @Barmar but, can you explain me more? thanks!!

Comment: I thought you'd understand, since you already did this for `marker`. I've posted an answer that shows it.

Comment: It works perfect!, thank you so much for the help @Barmar, this is a proyect for the school. Please let me ask you, I have to add info to the pop ups from two more calls, where I have to put them? My teacher help me with this so I dont quite understand the code, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Hard to be sure without seeing everything you need to do. I suggest you study how this works, and try to work it out on your own, that's how you learn and understand.

Comment: You are right @Barmar, do you know any tutorial on the web that maybe can help me to understand more ? about closure and javascript if im right. Thanks again.

Comment: google javascript closure

Comment: where i can add a function to show an icon while loading the markers on the map?

Comment: Put it in a hidden DIV. Show it before you call `$.getJSON`, and hide it in the success function.

Comment: many thanks again @Barmar! do you have any code snippet for help me?

Comment: Added something to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture `name` in the closure, just as you do for `marker`.

```
    $("#loadingDiv").show();
    $.getJSON('https://api.site.com/data/'+userID+'',(function(marker, name){ // second call using userID
      return function(data2) {
      var info1 = data2.response.tips.items[0].text;
      var info2 = data2.response.tips.items[1].text;
      marker.bindPopup("<div class='popup'>" + name +"</br>"+ info1 +"</br>"+ info2 + "</div>", {maxWidth: '600'}) // create the popup and add it to the marker
      $("#loadingDiv").hide();                   
            }
     })(marker, name)

<div id="#loadingDiv" style="display: none">Loading...</div>
```